# How can I get the transaction instructions from VerisonedTransaction object

Tags: web3.js, versionedtransactions

I need to get all the transaction instructions from the Versioned transaction object. Any idea about this?

Comment: Update your answer to state what you're starting with. For instance, are you starting with a versioned transaction in wire format (ie. raw bytes) or do you have a `VersionedTransaction` object in JavaScript?

Comment: I just have the VersionTransaction Object and I need to fetch the instructions from that

Answer (score 4):

The instructions are available in the transaction's `VersionedMessage`, which you can access like this:

```
const compiledInstructions = transaction.message.compiledInstructions;
```

Each instruction is a record of the following type:

```
type MessageCompiledInstruction = {
  /**
   * Ordered indices into the transaction keys array
   * indicating which accounts to pass to the program
   */
  accountKeyIndexes: number[];
  /**
   * The program input data
   */
  data: Uint8Array;
  /**
   * Index into the transaction keys array indicating the
   * program account that executes this instruction
   */
  programIdIndex: number;
};
```

Comment: But how indexes work with versioned transactions? Indexes there might be bigger than `transaction key array`

Comment: @RowanStone can you provide an example transaction you're trying to deserialize? An explorer link (or just base64 bytes) would go a long way toward helping us see what you're seeing.